# How do I wait for fetch to finish and load content before continuing with program execution

Tags: function, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

This is my function which gets data from a specific url and stores it in local storage, later on I will call it for a specific URL and display and work with content from local storage.

This fetch takes aproximately 1.5 seconds to resolve so things aren't displayed after first click on a button that calls this function.  How do I wait for fetch to finish and load content before continuing with program execution?

```js
function getContent(url) {
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(function store(data) {
            localStorage.clear();
            localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data.hits));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Request failed', error);
        });
}
```

This is what I tried

```js
async function getContent(url) {
    await fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(function store(data) {
            localStorage.clear();
            localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(data.hits));
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Request failed', error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this code:

```
async function getContent(url) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    localStorage.clear();
    localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data.hits));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error);
  }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thing was I had to use async on function I was calling get from, so it should wait for get to finish and load Storage.